# Change command menu background in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, menu, command, lwuit

Can we change `Command`'s background color of the menu in LWUIT ?

and how can I set an icon to the "Menu" generated `Command` ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain better than the other post. You can change the style of the Menu using and UIID.
There are two ways to do that.

Easy way. Use the LWUIT Resource editor and create in the Unselected tab, and UIID called Menu. In this UIID you should configure the background color as you wish. You can change more things (like text color, size of the font, etc)

Hard way, by code. Create a `Style` object and set it to the Menu.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, i want to set a background for the command list, i am already using a MenuRenderer, this is my menu:


http://i42.servimg.com/u/f42/11/52/17/11/screen11.png


what i want now is to set a background for my menu, and also an icon, is this possible in the source code ?

Comment: is possible but i will be so hard. If I were you I will try to do it with the resource editor.